# onClick to a new activity but the app stopped

Tags: java, php, android, listview, onclick

There is a listview showing all products. It is supposed that a new activity page which allows me to edit product(either save or delete)will be shown after I click the item on the listview. However, when I click the item, the app stopped with error message: Unfortunately, XXX(my app name) has stopped. Could anyone help ? Thank you !

EditProductActivity.java

```
public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

EditText txtName;
EditText txtPrice;
EditText txtDesc;
EditText txtCreatedAt;
Button btnSave;
Button btnDelete;

String pid;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// single product url
private static final String url_product_detials = "http://192.128.0.101/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

// url to update product
private static final String url_update_product = "http://192.128.0.101/android_connect/update_product.php";

// url to delete product
private static final String url_delete_product = "http://192.128.0.101/android_connect/delete_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);

    // save button
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

    // getting product details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting product id (pid) from intent
    pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

    // Getting complete product details in background thread
    new GetProductDetails().execute();

    // save button click event
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // starting background task to update product
            new SaveProductDetails().execute();
        }
    });

    // Delete button click event
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // deleting product in background thread
            new DeleteProduct().execute();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
 * */
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // product with this pid found
                        // Edit Text
                        txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                        txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                        txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                        // display product data in EditText
                        txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                        txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                        txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
 * */
class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Saving product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // getting updated data from EditTexts
        String name = txtName.getText().toString();
        String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));

        // sending modified data through http request
        // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check json success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully updated
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to update product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

/*****************************************************************
 * Background Async Task to Delete Product
 * */
class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Product...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Deleting product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_delete_product, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // product successfully deleted
                // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
}
```

Comment: The intended result should be like the video shown at 1:50

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D86beKXvjd0#t=111

Comment: where did you see PHP code here ? You still tagged under PHP .

Comment: there are 3 url in the code which are php files. The product list or product info is retrieved through php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using UI widgets from AsyncTask background thread:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

    // getting updated data from EditTexts
    String name = txtName.getText().toString();
    String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
    String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();
```

this throws exception. Move this code to onPreExecute (which is called on UI thread) and store in class variables, then use in doInBackground.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I cannot fully understand. I can find 3 onPreExecute methods within the same class. I don't know which method should I move the code into. Would you mind explaining what shoud I do in order to fix the problem ? Thank you

Comment: @CalvinNg you cant have three onPreExecute in single class,that would not compile. You have three AsyncTask derived classes that are inner to your Activity class. So you should move UI reading related code from SaveProductDetails.doInBackground to SaveProductDetails.onPreExecute.

Comment: @CalvinNg also you will get better answers if you include your logcat, you can copy paste it from eclipse LogCat window

Comment: I move :    String name = txtName.getText().toString();
    String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
    String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();   to onPreExecute. But the problem still exists.

Comment: logcat:
W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa62ca288)

E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: Fix all the places where you are doing anything with widgets on background thread, CANT help you more. Remember, android throws exceptions IF you touch UI from non UI thread. BTW. Exception you have attached is useless, admit it!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'd need to study more on UI thread in order to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, try to enable LogCat, it is in menu:
Window->Show view>Other>LogCat

Surround the code of action of listView with this try-catch, and modify any exception handlig code, to catch any throwable and logging it like this:

```
try {
  // Your code
} catch (Throwable t) 
{
  Log.e("error","error",t);
}
```

see the logcat output, should help.

Comment: The logcat says that: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: I try to comment the class "GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask", the "R.layout.edit_product" layout appears but I can't get the product details and when I click save button, the app crushes again. But, the delete function works. So I think it is the problem of the first 2 AsyncTask derived class: GetProductDetails and SaveProductDetails . I'd try to search some info about UI thread and try to fix the problem but failed. Could anyone help ? Thank you !